# Zend Expressive: How can I use zend-form view helpers?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, view-helpers, mezzio

How can I use zend-form view helpers?

doing so...
[How can I use zend-form view helpers?](http://zend-expressive.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.0/cookbook/using-zend-form-view-helpers/)

As a result, the message about the deprecated class contiguration
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip2pG.jpg)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this https://github.com/zendframework/zend-expressive/issues/335

Here's how my factory looks like:

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $config = $container->has('config') ? $container->get('config') : [];
        $config = isset($config['view_helpers']) ? $config['view_helpers'] : [];
        $manager = new HelperPluginManager($container, $config);

        return $manager;
    }
```

**Update:**

Since I was unclear let's try this again.

As you can see from the post on github, in order to remove the message about deprecated class you need to create a file `config/autoload/zend-form.global.php` with the contents:

```
<?php
use Zend\Form\ConfigProvider;

$provider = new ConfigProvider();
return $provider();
```

Doing so removes the need to add zend-form view helper configuration to service manager from within the factory that you are creating. 
Meaning lines

```
$formConfig = new FormHelperConfig();
$formConfig->configureServiceManager($manager);
```

are no longer needed.

Also, method `setServiceLocator` of `HelperPluginManager` is deprecated so you change these two lines:

```
$manager = new HelperPluginManager(new Config($config));
$manager->setServiceLocator($container);
```

to one line:

```
$manager = new HelperPluginManager($container, $config);
```

As result your `__invoke` function will look like this:

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $config = $container->has('config') ? $container->get('config') : [];
    $config = isset($config['view_helpers']) ? $config['view_helpers'] : [];
    $manager = new HelperPluginManager($container, $config);

    return $manager;
}
```

You use view helpers inside your view template. [Here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.view.helpers.html) you can find the list of all zend-form view helpers together with examples.

I hope this made thing more clear because I suck at explaining things.

Comment: How does this answer the question?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: Please provide detailed configuration structure?

Comment: I use `AbstractActionFactory`, how can I implement it. [https://xtreamwayz.com/blog/2015-12-30-psr7-abstract-action-factory-one-for-all]

Comment: @Drakulitka Forgive me but I have a feeling you don't know how to use view helpers. AbstractActionFactory has nothing to do with neither implementing or using view helpers. You use view helper within view template (.phtml file).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to implement
Sorry for my English